# openssl_pkcs12_read fails

Tags: php, php-openssl

I am trying to read a p12 formatted certificate file with php function `openssl_pkcs12_read`. My code looks like this:

```
<?php

$fname  = "./client-cert.p12";
$handle = fopen($fname, "r") or die ("Unable to open file!");
$p12buf = fread($handle, filesize($fname));
fclose($handle);
$certs = array();
$pass  = "bliblablup";

$result = openssl_pkcs12_read($p12buf, $certs, $pass);

if ( $result ) {
    print_r( $certs );
} else {
    print_r( "Error!\r\n");
}
```

I am always running into the error-branch of `if($result) ...` and cannot find any information how to get more details on the error condition. Any hints welcome.

Comment: you are not doing any checks on file opening/reading. Are you 100% that is working alright?

Comment: I did some checks: I printed $p12buf to stdout and was also trying with an invalid filename to compare the behaviour. It looked to me as if the content of the client-cert.p12 file arrives in $p12buf.

Comment: (regarding the closing `?>`, not related to your problem, but since you edited it back: is usually considered a bad practice to leave a trailing closing tag in php unless it is explicitly needed)

Comment: I had no idea (and removed it again).

Comment: It's probably not it, but instead of "looks to me", add a proper error check after opening the file, and `die()` there if you fail to open the file. That would make it clearer to us observers there is no other error going on.

Comment: echo openssl_error_string() after the read to see the error.

Comment: use file_get_contents instead of fread, that should work